# I want to remove a garden bed which is on the side of my driveway and fill it with concrete. What do I need to know?

Tags: concrete, driveway

The photo shows the either end of the garden bed along a driveway.

Garden bed is not very well built and uses a mix of assorted bricks.

The size is about 15m long and 0.5m wide.

I have no idea how deep is the garden bed.

If I ask someone to remove all the plant and soil, dismantle the garden bed and level the hole with concrete, what should I be aware about this kind of project?

For example, does the kind of concrete matter? Do I need rebar for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it freeze in your location in the world? If so, how deep? Do you know the location of **all** your utility lines (Sewer, water, gas, electric, telephone, tv cable, *etcetera*) and if any of them are beneath this flowerbed? If not, do you know who to call to get those marked before work commences?

Comment: It is possible you just need to remove the bricks and dirt.  It might just be sitting on top of the surface of the driveway/walkway.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank for your comment. It doesn't freeze in my location which is Sydney Australia.

Comment: @crip659 I actually put in some plants there before. It seems to go deeper than the driveway surface. But yeah, hopefully it is not too deep.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to make a 6 inch thick concrete for drive way, or 3 inch concrete for walk way the process is the same.

After removing the appropriate depth of dirt, lay a layer of crushed rock on the dirt.

Place a spacer (I use Bender Board) between the old concrete and new concrete (for expansion). Also place a Bender Board between the new concrete and the fence. After the concrete has started to set, remove the spacers, do not wait too long otherwise they can not be removed.

Pour concrete, do not let it dry, keep wet/moist for at least day.

While the concrete is still workable use trowel to round up the edges.

Must keep concrete moist/wet for at least a day or longer.

Comment: ..short about 6-27 days on the moist cure according to pretty much all concrete engineering resources. *e.g.* http://dl.mycivil.ir/dozanani/ACI/ACI%20308R-01%20R08%20Guide%20to%20Curing%20Concrete_MyCivil.ir.pdf

Comment: @Ecnerwal the first 24 hours are most critical, but I accept your comment